# Automatically disabling one layer when another layer is turned on

Tags: arcgis-online

I wanted to find a way to have one layer automatically turn off when another layer was turned on, but was unable to find a way to do this in ArcGIS Online. Is this operation possible in ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

I don't this is possible in an ArcGIS Online map, think what you are asking, you want a layer to respond to an on-click event in the table of contents. There is no place to set such an action, well not that I'm aware of. The nearest equivalence is creating yourself a Web App using the Web App builder. Under your content click on the create button > Configurable Apps > Compare Maps/Layers > then try the spy glass. This will allow you to show one layer on/off as you move the spyglass around.

Now it may be possible to create your action if someone develops a website, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about that aspect of web mapping to suggest an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done using layer actions:

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-dashboards-ideas/arcgis-dashboards-select-multiple-targets-when/idi-p/1026343

You set a non-layer element on a toggle, and when that changes, turn a layer on or off, checking the the 'render when filtered' box.